# How to create Full Screen width jtoolbar

Tags: java, swing, jtoolbar

I created full screen jform using netbeans in java. I need to create Full Screen width sized jtoolbar. How I do this?

this code I use for create full screen size jform / jform resize

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
setBounds(0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [`JToolBar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JToolBar.html) inherithed method [`Component::setBounds`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)).

Place ToolBar at TOP:

```
toolBar.setBounds(0, 0, screenSize.width, yourDesiredHeight);
```

Place ToolBar at BOTTOM:

```
toolBar.setBounds(0, screensize.height - yourDesiredHeight, screenSize.width, yourDesiredHeight);
```